# When using token_get_all(), how do I determine if a "lonely" T_STRING is a function call, a constant or something else?

Tags: php, parsing, token, php-parser

***Minimal example code:***

```
<?php

    $avarname = 'a var value';

    function a_function_name($a_parameter = true)
    {
        // a comment
    }

    a_function_name();
```

***Structure from using token_get_all():***

```
T_OPEN_TAG: <?php
T_WHITESPACE:
T_VARIABLE: $avarname
T_WHITESPACE:
T_WHITESPACE:
T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING: 'a var value'
T_WHITESPACE:
T_FUNCTION: function
T_WHITESPACE:
T_STRING: a_function_name
T_VARIABLE: $a_parameter
T_WHITESPACE:
T_WHITESPACE:
T_STRING: true
T_WHITESPACE:
T_WHITESPACE:
T_COMMENT: // a comment
T_WHITESPACE:
T_WHITESPACE:
T_STRING: a_function_name
T_WHITESPACE:
```

As you can see, one can detect a function ***definition*** by checking for a ***T_STRING***, preceded by a ***T_WHITESPACE***, preceded by a ***T_FUNCTION***. So far, so good.

**However**, a function ***call*** is just a ***T_STRING***, just like many other things, such as the "true" constant for the parameter, with no special symbol either before or after it.

How am I supposed to know if a ***T_STRING*** refers to a function name or something else when there is no symbol prior to it telling my interpreter what the next ***T_STRING*** is supposed to refer to?

If your answer will be that I need to check if a function exists with the name of the T_STRING value, does that mean that there cannot be a function called true()? Since that would conflict with the "true" constant? If I need to make such a check, it complicates things in many different ways...

Comment: Well, that's just the difference between tokenizer and parser. One breaks up the code into sections. The other must look at context and relation.

Answer (score 2):

What `token_get_all` *actually* returns is this (with already post-processed token names):

```
  ...,
  [26]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "T_STRING"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "a_function_name"
    [2]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [27]=>
  string(1) "("
  [28]=>
  string(1) ")"
```

`token_get_all` only does the *tokenisation*, it doesn't parse the parts into a logical AST. The next step after this would be to look at how the tokens fit together and what logical units they form. Here you'd parse the three consecutive tokens "`a_function_name`", "`(`" and "`)`" into meaning *a function call*.

You may want to use an existing [PHP Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser), instead of reinventing this step from scratch.